# How to install ion-google-place in ionic cordova application?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, google-maps, ionic-framework, google-maps-android-api-2

I use [following](https://github.com/israelidanny/ion-google-place) tutorial to install (ion-google-place) but I found sth.

my error is:

```
bower EMALFORMED    Failed to read /home/binov1/ElolinkProjectversion2/bower.json

Additional error details:
Unexpected token $
```

my bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "HelloIonic",
  "private": "true",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ionic": "driftyco/ionic-bower#1.1.1"
  }
}
$ bower install ng-cordova-oauth -S
```

Comment: What is actually your problem?

Comment: my problem is when i excute this command (bower install ion-google-place) i have this error "bower EMALFORMED    Failed to read /home/binov1/ElolinkProjectversion2/bower.json"

Comment: Probably you have syntax errors in your bower.json. Can you please post your bower.json file here and your error stack?

Comment: Look to my question please, I edit it

Comment: Please remove this line `$ bower install ng-cordova-oauth -S` from bower.json and try again

Answer (score 1):

You can install `ion-google-place` after first creating the app. Here are quick instructions on how to do that:

source: http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/

1. Install node.js
2. Install cordov and ionic: `npm install -g cordova ionic`
3. Create your project folder: `ionic start myApp tabs` or choose a template of your choice
4. Move to your project folder: `cd myApp`
5. Create platform (iOS, Android, etc.): `ionic platform add ios`
6. Build the app: `ionic build ios`
7. Open emulator: `ionic emulate ios`
8. You can then install the plugin: `bower install ion-google-place`
9. Insert the your Google Maps javascript API:
   `<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>`
10. Add `ion-google-place` dependency on your ionic app:

    ```
     angular.module('myApp', [
         'ionic',
         'ion-google-place'
     ]);
    ```
11. In your HTML markup, you can use the directive like this:

    ```
     <ion-google-place placeholder="Enter an address, Apt# and ZIP" ng-model="location" />
    ```

Comment: if this still doesn't work for you, add this script and link tags into your head: `<script src="lib/ion-google-place/ion-google-place.js"></script>
    <link href="lib/ion-google-place/ion-google-place.css">`